# How to remove numbering on PolarArea circles?

Tags: chart.js

If you look at the [example of PolarArea in the Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/polar.html), you will see each circle has a number like 16, 14, 12, etc.

These numbers refer to the value of each segment.

Is it possible to remove these numbers so the chart displays with the segments and circles only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the [ticks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#tick-options) on the [linear radial axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html). They can be removed by setting the `scale.ticks.display` option to `false`.

Example:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: "polarArea",
  data: {
    labels: ["a", "b", "c"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [10, 20, 30]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scale: {
      ticks: {
        display: false
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```